How to send transaction bundles?
How can I send these transactions/bundle them as one transaction and send them?

You can use the sendBundle RPC endpoint from Jito for this. From their docs:

Submits a bundled list of signed transaction(s) (base-58 encoded string) to the cluster for processing. The transactions will be atomically processed in order, meaning if any of the transactions fail, the entire bundle won’t be processed (all or nothing).
Please note that a tip is necessary for the bundle to considered.


A tip can be any instruction, top-level or CPI, that transfers SOL to
one of the 8 tip accounts. Clients should make sure they have balance
and state assertions that allow the tip to only go thru conditionally,
especially if tipping as a separate tx. If the tip is low, there is a
chance that the bundle does not get selected during the auction. You
can get the tip accounts using getTipAccounts. Ideally select one of
the accounts in random to reduce contention.

In practice this then looks like so (example from the docs as well):
curl https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/bundles -X POST -H curl https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/bundles -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "sendBundle",
  "params": [
    [
      "4VbvoRYXFaXzDBUYfMXP1irhMZ9XRE6F1keS8GbYzKxgdpEasZtRv6GXxbygPp3yBVeSR4wN9JEauSTnVTKjuq3ktM3JpMebYpdGxZWUttJv9N2DzxBm4vhySdq2hbu1LQX7WxS2xsHG6vNwVCjP33Z2ZLP7S5dZujcan1Xq5Z2HibbbK3M3LD59QVuczyK44Fe3k27kVQ43oRH5L7KgpUS1vBoqTd9ZTzC32H62WPHJeLrQiNkmSB668FivXBAfMg13Svgiu9E",
      "6HZu11s3SDBz5ytDj1tyBuoeUnwa1wPoKvq6ffivmfhTGahe3xvGpizJkofHCeDn1UgPN8sLABueKE326aGLXkn5yQyrrpuRF9q1TPZqqBMzcDvoJS1khPBprxnXcxNhMUbV78cS2R8LrCU29wjYk5b4JpVtF23ys4ZBZoNZKmPekAW9odcPVXb9HoMnWvx8xwqd7GsVB56R343vAX6HGUMoiB1WgR9jznG655WiXQTff5gPsCP3QJFTXC7iYEYtrcA3dUeZ3q4YK9ipdYZsgAS9H46i9dhDP2Zx3"
    ]
  ]
}
'

